# Get day name and number of times day repeat in date range in swift

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I have a scenario in which I get a date from backend API, I get a start date and end date, now I want to first check the day on that date, for example, today is `8-11-2019` is Friday, and end date is `20-11-2019`. Now I want to check each date day name and also a number of times day are repeating in this date range. For example if Friday is twice in this date range then I want to get those dates on click of Friday, The dates range are dynamic it can vary. Example check in screen shot,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code :

```
let startDate : Date = Date()
let endDate : Date = Date()


let calendar = Calendar.current

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS"

let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "EEEE"

let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate) //returns number of days

var date : Date = startDate

var numberOfDays : [String : (Int,[Date])] = ["Sunday" : (0, []), "Monday" : (0, []), "Tuesday" : (0, []), "Wednesday" : (0, []), "Thursday" : (0, []), "Friday" : (0, []), "Saturday" : (0, [])]

while date <= date2 {

    let day : String = dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
    print(day)

    if let value = numberOfDays[day] {
        var tempDateArr = value.1
        tempDateArr.append(date)
        numberOfDays[day] = ((value.0 + 1), tempDateArr)

    }
    date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
}

print(numberOfDays) //  number of times day are repeating
```

Comment: Will this return me date as respect to day, like if sunday are two in range then on click sunday it should give me that two dates for sunday. @SGDEV

Comment: Yes, in dictionary we have a tuple in which first value have numberOfCount and second value have a array of dates and the key is Day(Sunday, Monday, etc), so have all the data that you required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it. @SGDev

Answer (score 0):

The below function return an [Int: Int] dictionary, where the key is the weekday (as defined by the current calendar) and the value is the number of occurrences in the date range

```
func distributionOfDays(from date1: Date, to date2:Date) -> [Int:Int]{
  var date = min(date1, date2)
  let endDate = max(date1, date2)
  var days = [Int:Int]()
  while date <= endDate {
     let day = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)
     days[day] = (days[day] ?? 0) + 1
     date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
  }
  return days
```

If you want, you can format/output the data using something like this:

```
let days = distributionOfDays(from: date1, to: date2).sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key})
days.forEach{
   print("\(Calendar.current.shortWeekdaySymbols[$0.key - 1]), \($0.value)")
}
```

Need to subtract - 1 from the key as the `.weekday` component is 1-indexed, and `shortWeekDaySymbols` is 0-indexed.

Comment: Ooops.  This somewhat duplicates SGDev's earlier answer that hadn't been posted when I started typing, although it takes a different approach by sticking with the Calendar functions.  You now have a choice of valid approaches :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it.:) .@flanker